# CI failed because of node-sass, on Ionic 4 and nodeV12

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, ionic4, node-sass

I'm facing an issue in my developpement, I develop an app with ionic v4 and I had a continuous integration for test on Gitlab. Locally my test and build pass, but on the server-side for the ci it failed.
First time, I had an error which was :

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
```

After that made many change in my .gitlab-ci.yml like,

- npm rebuild node-sass
- npm rebuild node-sass --force
- npm run clean
- rm -rf node_modules and package-lock.json
- ionic repair
- npm uninstall node-sass and npm install node-sass (and with spécific version 12+)

I tried in all order and failed, after more research I've see that the server have not same node and npm versions, So I updated my side to the same version locally :

```
C:\Users\Ludovic\Documents\gototalentMobile>node -v
v12.13.1

C:\Users\Ludovic\Documents\gototalentMobile>npm -v
6.12.0
```

After that I alway have my ci which failed, what I see is that there is an ionic script (or angular) which is executed all time and install a node-sass version incompatible with node 12 :

```
> node-sass@4.10.0 install /builds/hrit/gototalentMobile/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.10.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

Problem here is that I don't know where is this script, I tried many things to install the node-sassV12+ in my dependencies, but it create always a dependency to V10 in my package-lock.json. I think the problem came from here, node-sass@10.0.0 will not work with NodeV12 but I don't know where change this.

I let here all my informations :

Ionic cordova

```
C:\Users\Ludovic\Documents\gototalentMobile>ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.4.0 (C:\Users\Ludovic\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, ios 5.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   NodeJS : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.12.0
   OS     : Windows 7
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "talentmoovmobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev": "ionic cordova run android --device",
    "ci-staging-build": "ng build --configuration=staging",
    "staging": "ionic cordova run android --configuration=staging --device",
    "test-ci": "ng test --watch=false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "latest",
    "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/sockjs-client": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.27.1",
    "call-number": "1.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cordova": "^8.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.1",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-chooser": "1.2.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "0.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "ion2-calendar": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
    "ionic4-rating": "^1.0.9",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
    "node-gyp": "^6.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-chooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "call-number": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Actual .gitlab-ci.yml which failed too

```
# https://gitlab.com/ci/lint
# https://gitlab.com/ci/lint
# This image is based from node and includes what we need to run tests with Chrome headless
image: weboaks/node-karma-protractor-chrome:headless

variables:

stages:
  - test
  - build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass@4.13.0
    - npm cache clean --force
    - npm install --ignore-scripts
    - npm run test-ci
  tags:
    - pages

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass@4.13.0
    - npm cache clean --force
    - npm install --ignore-scripts
    - npm run ci-staging-build
  tags:
    - pages
  dependencies:
    - test
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="fr.hritconsulting.talentmoov" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>TalentMoov</name>
    <description>From HR'IT Consulting Teams.</description>
    <author email="contact@hr-itconsulting.com" href="https://www.hr-itconsulting.com/">HR'IT Consulting WebSite</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-chooser" spec="1.2.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filechooser" spec="1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="0.9.0-beta.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="0.9.2">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="mx.ferreyra.callnumber" spec="~0.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="2.2.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="3.0.2" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="5.0.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.1" />
</widget>
```

I'm blocked on this issue since many days. I required you're help now and thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue before.

Node-sass was a dependency of @angular-devkit/build-angular, so if you change its version to 0.13.9 it will require Node-sass 4.12.0, and then it should be fine.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
...
}
```

Let me know if that worked for you

Comment: Also did you know you could use `npm ci` in the command line and it would install FASTER all the dependencies you had defined in the package-lock.json

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work, the postInstall script is not more call ! I have another error now : HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms. But I will check in my side.

Comment: Not sure, can you explain what are you trying to do? Maybe this is related - https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T200347

Comment: I try to run test for ionic only once for my CI with : ng test --watch=false

Answer (score 0):

@Monomachus The error after updated the dependency is :

```
$ npm run test-ci

> talentmoovmobile@1.0.0 test-ci /builds/hrit/gototalentMobile
> ng test --watch=false

03 12 2019 13:32:37.154:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
03 12 2019 13:32:37.162:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeCI with concurrency unlimited
03 12 2019 13:32:37.205:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromiumHeadless
03 12 2019 13:33:32.531:INFO [HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket YJ3SzogXy4FFB2VGAAAA with id 69484878
03 12 2019 13:34:05.648:WARN [HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (0 times), because no message in 30000 ms.
HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms.

HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms.

03 12 2019 13:34:22.775:WARN [launcher]: ChromiumHeadless was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! talentmoovmobile@1.0.0 test-ci: `ng test --watch=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the talentmoovmobile@1.0.0 test-ci script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2019-12-03T13_34_37_826Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Check this thread: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/154 -> maybe you'll find working solutions there